# What is Nephalem Glory, and what does it do?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

In the *D3* demo, I've seen a few yellow orbs drop that produce a "Nephalem Glory" buff (that I've never seen in the PC version), but since I have no mouse, I cannot mouseover and figure out what the heck it does. The buff doesn't appear to do much, at least.

What does the buff do? Do they stack? Is there a cap? How long does it last? What are its drop conditions?

Comment: In the console version, if you want to see what a certain buff or debuff does, you can hit `select` (or whatever button gets you to your inventory-skills-etc) and tab over to a section that shows you active buffs on you. That tends to have a decent description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/combat-skills#power-globes):

> In the Xbox 360 and PlayStation®3 versions of Diablo III, vanquished monsters may leave behind **power globes**—golden-colored infusions of energy— that you can pick up by moving near them.
>
> Picking up a power globe triggers a burst of energy that strikes nearby enemies for a percentage of your damage, and also grants you and nearby allies the **Nephalem Glory** buff. Nephalem Glory lasts 60 seconds, after which a secondary damaging energy burst will also be triggered.
>
> Picking up additional power globes while Nephalem Glory is active will level up the power of this energy burst by up to three times; it will also reset the duration of the buff to 60 seconds. Picking up health globes will extend the duration of Nephalem Glory by 5 seconds, and every five health globes will also level up the power of the effect by 1 (again, up to a maximum of three increases).
>
> - **Nephalem Glory – Level 1** - While Nephalem Glory is active, heroes will deal bonus damage with every attack.
> - **Nephalem Glory – Level 2** - With two levels of Nephalem Glory, heroes will will deal bonus damage that also carries over to nearby enemies with every attack. Additionally, heroes gain 10% bonus movement speed.
> - **Nephalem Glory – Level 3** - With three levels of Nephalem Glory, heroes will deal bonus damage with every attack that also carries over to nearby enemies. Each hit you land while the buff is active has a chance of creating a damaging explosion.

So, it adds bonus damage plus an immediate burst damage and, as it stacks up to three times, it adds speed, chain damage and random burst damage, followed by burst damage when it runs out. It lasts 60 seconds by default, but all orb pickups will act in ways to extend this duration. It drops entirely randomly along with other globes when vanquishing an enemy.